# Is it possible to cut flexible solar PV panels down to size to suit small IoT type devices?

Tags: solar-cell, energy-harvesting

I've been looking for a supplier for tiny (approx 10mm x 30mm x 1mm) PV cells that you find on solar powered calculators without any success.  Is it possible to cut a larger flex amorphous Si panel down to size without specialized tools? Or does anyone have suggestions on how I might get small quantities of a PV cell(s) of the approx dimensions mentioned above.

[Edit: the keyword I should have been using in my searches is 'thin film'. I'm now finding products of suitable dimensions, including cuttable foil from a company called Infinity PV].

Comment: Short answer, 'no'. Find a manufacturer that can build one in a custom format, you'll probably pay a lot and be expected to order large quantities. Product recommendations are off topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solar cells from infinityPV.com can be cut to the dimension you like, see the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SJuIl-gd8g

/Jon

Comment: Thanks Jon. Actually found tiny panels like those used in calculators on Aliexpress (product code 1854641441) which I used in the end. The inifinityPV product looks very interesting, but between postage and minimum order it was a little more than I was willing to spend at the time.